# Prob. 12, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: The first, second, and third derivatives of $f(x) = |x|^3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

Here is Prob. 12, Chap. 5 in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> If $f(x) = |x|^3$, compute $f^\prime(x)$, $f^{\prime\prime}(x)$ for all real $x$, and show that $f^{(3)}(0)$ does not exist.

My Attempt:

> We can also write the formula for $f$ as 
>   $$ 
> f(x) =
> \begin{cases} 
> x^3 \ \mbox{ if $x > 0$}, \\ 
> 0 \ \mbox{ if $x = 0$}, \\ 
> - x^3 \ \mbox{ if $x < 0$}.
> \end{cases} 
> $$
>   Then 
>   $$f^\prime(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(h) -f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|h|^3}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} |h|^2  \mathrm{sgn} (h) = 0.$$ 
>   Thus
>   $$ 
> f^\prime(x) =
> \begin{cases} 
> 3x^2 \ \mbox{ if $x > 0$}, \\ 
> 0 \ \mbox{ if $x = 0$}, \\ 
> - 3x^2 \ \mbox{ if $x < 0$}.
> \end{cases} 
> $$
>   That is, 
>   $$f^\prime(x) = 3x^2 \mathrm{sgn}(x).$$
>   Now 
>   $$ f^{\prime\prime}(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f^\prime(h) - f^\prime(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ 3h^2 \mathrm{sgn} (h) }{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} 3h \ \mathrm{sgn} (h) = 0.$$
>   Thus 
>   $$ 
> f^{\prime\prime}(x) =
> \begin{cases} 
> 6x \ \mbox{ if $x > 0$}, \\ 
> 0 \ \mbox{ if $x = 0$}, \\ 
> - 6x^ \ \mbox{ if $x < 0$}.
> \end{cases} 
> $$
>   That is, 
>   $$f^{\prime\prime}(x) = 6x\  \mathrm{sgn} (x).$$
>   Now 
>   $$f^{(3)}(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(h) - f^{\prime\prime}(0) }{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} 6 \mathrm{sgn}(h), $$
>   and this limit does not exist, as it is $+1$ as $h \to 0+$ and is $-1$ as $h \to 0-$.

Is my calculation correct?

Comment: Seems right. The point is that $f''(x) = 6|x|$ if you rewrite it. I think it is well known that this function has no derivative at $0$.

Comment: In my opinion there just exists a very minor error that is possibly a simple typo; the absolute value of the right and left limits of $6$sgn$(h)$ as $h \to 0$ is $6$ instead of $1$. But this does not affect the essential. :) Keep it up!